# android - text input type person name isn't working

Tags: android, text

In my android project I want a textfield of type personname where by default caps lock is activated, however, this code isn't working.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_user_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Why might this not work?

EDIT: here is the xml code to show what the file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/t_registration"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="7dp" 
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"/>


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:stretchColumns="1" >
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_user_name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.0"
                android:text="User Name * :   " />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_user_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>



        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_first_name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.0"
                android:text="First Name * :   " />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_first_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" >
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_last_name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.0"
                android:text="Last Name * :   " />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_last_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" >
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_email_address"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.0"
                android:text="Email Address:   " />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_email_address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_school_id"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.0"
                android:text="school_id * :   " />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_school_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:inputType="text" >
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_password"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.0"
                android:text="Password * :   " />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:inputType="textPassword" >

            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_confirm_password"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.0"
                android:text="Confirm password * :   " />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_password2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:inputType="textPassword" >"
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_image_select"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.0"
                android:text="Image Select * :   " />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b_image_browse"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/b_image_browse"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:onClick="b_image_browse_action" />

        </TableRow>           

    </TableLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_image_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:hint="Image File Path"
        android:inputType="text" >
    </EditText>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >


       <Button
           android:id="@+id/b_reg_Cancel"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_margin="10dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
           android:padding="10dp"
           android:text="@string/b_reg_Cancel"
           android:textSize="15dp"
           android:onClick="b_reg_Cancel_action" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_reg_Submit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/b_reg_Submit"
            android:textSize="15dp" 
            android:onClick="b_reg_Submit_action"/>

    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, because the code you posted looks fine to me.  Probably is something else in your xml? can you post the whole thing?

Comment: You want the whole thing caps or just the first letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to display person name as normal, try this: `android:capitalize="words"`. If you want to all caps you can change `words` into `characters` or doing like Mr. LuxuryMode said!

Edited:

You should remove `android:inputType="textPersonName"` field. It will work!

Comment: `android:capitalize` is deprecated. Solution from @ViliusK works fine for me.

Answer (score 16):

Use

```
android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
```

as using only `"textPersonName"` is not enough so name's first letters would be capitalized.

Similarly with postal addresses:

```
android:inputType="textPostalAddress|textCapSentences"
```

Comment: What a wonderful and well-written framework Android is! It always amazes me how many workarounds you have to make to get things working.

Answer (score 1):

I used this for the caps words and no suggestion

```
android:inputType="textCapWords|textNoSuggestions"
```

e.g. `Tom Hanks`

Answer (score 0):

If you want all caps, just use `android:textAllCaps="true"`

Comment: It's worth noting that this is only supported in APIs 14+. Supporting versions previous to that require making your own extension of `EditText` which converts the string to caps when changed.

Comment: the target of my android is 2.1